# Passport needed for flight to Guadeloupe (PTP) from Paris-Orly (ORY) for German citizens?

Tags: passports, france, german-citizens, guadeloupe

Is a passport needed for a German citizen flying from ORY --> PTP directly?

What I have found already was:

> "U. a. Deutsche können für Aufenthalte von bis zu 90 Tagen mit noch
>   mindestens 6 Monate gültigem Personalausweis einreisen. Erfolgt die
>   An- und Abreise jedoch über Drittstaaten, ist ein Reisepass
>   notwendig."

[Source](https://www.derreisefuehrer.com/guides/karibik/guadeloupe/passport-visa/)

Roughly translated:
"If you are a German citizen you can fly to Guadeloupe with a normal ID (at least 6 months valid) for a stay of less than 90 days - in case you are not traveling from/over a third state."

I sent a similar question to visas-francfort-de@diplomatie.gouv.fr
but they haven't replied for the last 1-2 months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Timatic](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) (the database used by airlines to show a county's entry requirements, and thus by extension whether the airline will allow you to board the flight) says you may enter Guadeloupe, an overseas department of France, visa-free with a German passport, or specific other German documents. Here's a copy-and-paste:

> / 18FEB19 / 1725 UTC
>
> National Germany (DE)            Destination French West Indies (GP)
>
> French West Indies (GP)
>
> Passport required.
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be   valid for the period of intended stay.
>
> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of Germany with a national ID card.
> - Nationals of Germany with a temporary passport.
>
> VISA NOT REQUIRED.

Comment: So, to get this right, as a german citizien I can enter without a passport - only with my german national ID-Card?

Comment: @TopQuestions Yes, that's what Timatic says. And...yes, I hadn't thought of text-to-speech readers. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F10610

Finally got an answer on an official site - here is this stated, 20th of February 2019:

> Si vous êtes européen, vous pouvez entrer et séjourner jusqu'à 3 mois
>   en France (y compris outre-mer) sans formalité particulière.
>
> Vous devez simplement vous munir d'un passeport ou d'un titre
>   d'identité en cours de validité, en cas de contrôle d'identité sur le
>   territoire.
>
> La possession d'un de ces 2 documents vous permet de séjourner
>   librement en France.

Roughly translated:

> If you are european, you can travel in/enter france for up to 3
>   (three) months (including overseas) without doing any paperwork.
>
> There is just an ID or a passport needed to identify yourself (in
>   France).
>
> If you have one of both (ID or Passport) you are allowed to travel
>   freely in france

Answer (score 0):

Guadeloupe (like France's other overseas *départements*: Martinique, French Guiana, Mayotte, Réunion) is in the European Union. Therefore the EU freedom of movement rules apply: as an EU (and more generally EEA) national, you can visit for a short time, and you can settle if you're economically self-sufficient (to summarize the rules at a very high level). An EEA national id card is sufficient to prove that you are an EEA national.

This does not automatically apply to France's other overseas territories, which are not in the EU. However, I think the (populated) French territories all at least allow EEA nationals to visit with a national ID — but you'll probably need a passport to get there from Europe anyway.

For non EU/EEA nationals, a Schengen visa does not in general allow visiting Guadeloupe (and vice versa). Visa exemption rules are also different in different overseas *départements* and territories.